# How do I get to these blessed variables?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use an obscurely documented library that seems to be returning something blessed

`bless` has never made sense even after reading a number of attempts at explaining it, so I'll just ask the simple question of how do I get to these member variables?

The error message seems to conflict with the `Data::Dumper` output, though on the off chance that `$vm_ds` needed to be blessed, I tried adding "bless($vm_ds, 'ManagedObjectReference');" in and just got

> Not a HASH reference at blib/lib/Class/MethodMaker/scalar.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Class/MethodMaker/scalar/scal0000.al) line 252.

for my trouble.

```
    my $vm_ds = $vm_view->datastore;

    print "--datastore--\n";

    print Dumper($vm_ds);

    print "vm_ds1: ", $vm_ds->value, "\n";

    exit 0;
```

```
$VAR1 = [
      bless( {
           'value' => 'filer01-cvo-2.fs.peak.org:/vol/vmfs01',
           'type' => 'Datastore'
         }, 'ManagedObjectReference' )
    ];
Can't call method "value" on unblessed reference at ./getvms line 93.
```

Comment: $vm_ds->{value} doesn't work either?

Comment: I did try that and it gives "not a hash reference"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$vm_ds` is a reference to an array (hence the `[ ... ]` in Dumper output) with one item being an instance of class `ManagedObjectReference` (this is the meaning of bless: saying that something is an instance of some class)
So you need to do `$vm_ds->[0]->value()` instead of `$vm_ds->value()`. 0 will be the first item in the array (your example shows only one item, but in a generic case your array reference may contain multiple items).

Comment: I just noticed that and if fact $vm_ds->[0]->{'value'} does work.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but with objects you should stick to the class API as long as possible hence using methods defined in class to access elements (such as `->value()`) instead of poking directly inside the underlying variable (`->{'value'}`).

Answer (score 5):

`$vm_ds` is a reference to an array of one blessed hash, so it is `$vm_ds->[0]` that is blessed into `ManagedObjectReference`. You can extract the `value` field using `$vm_ds->[0]{value}`, but it is very wrong to access object atributes directly like this, and is equivalent to accessing a private attribute

`bless` is Perl's object-oriented mechanism, and the class that a data item is blessed into specifies which Perl package contains the methods and data for the class

Somewhere you have a `.pm` file with `package ManagedObjectReference` and a number of subroutines which are the methods for the class. These supply the official interface to the class, and if you're lucky then there is a `value` method which is the accessor method for the `value` attribute. Try calling `$vm_ds->[0]->value()` and see if that works, otherwise you need to read the documentation for your `ManagedObjectReference` class

Comment: Yes, you're right, and if the documentation were comprehensible I would.  When I get a chance, I'll try reading the code as the accessors probably won't be too hard to fine.